# Moving a point along the direction of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am finding the language of this linear algebra problem a little confusing.

the question is :

```
 "a Point A = (x,y) and a vector v = (a,b). If I move by one unit length from Point A in 
  the direction of v, what is the new Point B I arrive at?"
```

I just wanted to confirm that the solution will be a simple B = (x+a,y+b) or am I still missing something????

Comment: If you move from A to B $=(x+a,y+b)$, then you're moving by a length equal to the length of the vector, which is $|v|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. The question asks you to move only a length of $1$.

Comment: is it asking me to calculate the projection of a on v???

Comment: Not exactly. Try drawing the situation: a point A, a direction (from the point) given by a vector v, and the move of from A in the direction of v, but with length 1 (for ilustration purpose, draw v with length different from 1). It will probably help you understand the exercise.

Comment: In which way is this question related to linear algebra? Is there any linear transformation involved?

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way to do it. You need to find the [unit vector](https://byjus.com/maths/unit-vector/#:%7E:text=A%20vector%20is%20a%20quantity,%2B32) of $v$, and then move it by coordinates of that unit vector, which we'll denote as $v_0$. So we have $\displaystyle v_0=\frac{(a,b)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$. Now you can do what you did so the solution will be $\displaystyle B\left(x+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},y+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$.